# Multiplexing submodules

Tags: verilog

I need to design a rightshift unit that have 4 module (logic,rotate,rotate with carry and arithmetic shift). I've written each module individual and they all work, but I need a multiplexer to recall each module in shift module.

```
module lshr(a,lout);
  input [7:0]a;
  output [7:0]out;
  assign lout[7]=0;
  assign lout[6:0]= a[7:1];
endmodule

module rshr(a,rout);
  input [7:0]a;
  output [7:0]rout;
  assign rout[7]=a[0];
  assign rout[6:0]= a[7:1];
endmodule

module rcshr(a,cin,rcout);
  input [7:0]a;
  input cin;
  output [7:0]rcout;
  assign rcout[7]=cin;
  assign rcout[6:0]= a[7:1];
endmodule

module ashr(a,aout);
  input [7:0]a;
  output [7:0]aout;
  assign aout[7]=a[7];
  assign aout[6:0]=a[7:1];
endmodule

module mux418bit(a,b,c,d,s0,s1,e);
  input[7:0]a,b,c,d;
  input s0,s1;
  output[7:0]e;

module sru(a,cin,s0,s1,out);
  input[7:0]a;
  input cin
  input s0,s1;
  output[7:0]out;
  ????? i dont know what to do here!
endmodule
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is use modules that you've created as submodules in `sru` module, i.e.:

```
module sru(a,cin,s0,s1,out);
  input[7:0]a;
  input cin;
  input s0,s1;
  output [7:0]out;

  wire [7:0] lshr_out, rshr_out, rcshr_out, ashr_out;

  lshr  m1(a, lshr_out);
  rshr  m2(a, rshr_out);
  rcshr m3(a, cin, rcshr_out);
  ashr  m4(a, ashr_out);

  mux418bit m5(lshr_out, rshr_out, rcshr_out, ashr_out, s0, s1, out);

endmodule
```

As you can see, your four modules (`lshr`, `rshr`, `rcshr`, `ashr`) were declared as submodules inside `sru` (`m1`,...,`m5`). The output from these modules is multiplexed (inside `m5` submodule) depending on `s0` and `s1` values (`case` construct is responsible for that).

You can check that this code compiles without any errors [here](http://www.edaplayground.com/x/HNw).

One other thing, your `mux418bit` module is not finished. Probably you want to achieve something like this:

```
module mux418bit(a,b,c,d,s0,s1,e);
  input[7:0]a,b,c,d;
  input s0,s1;
  output reg [7:0]e;

  always @(*) begin
    case({s0,s1})
      2'b00 : e = a;
      2'b01 : e = b;
      2'b10 : e = c;
      2'b11 : e = d;
    endcase
  end

endmodule
```

In situation when you can't use `case` construct:

```
module mux418bit(a,b,c,d,s0,s1,e);
  input[7:0]a,b,c,d;
  input s0,s1;
  output [7:0]e;

  assign e = ({s0,s1} == 2'b00) ? a : 
             ({s0,s1} == 2'b01) ? b :
             ({s0,s1} == 2'b10) ? c : d;
endmodule
```

Comment: Thanks for answer,but i was told by my professor not to use case and .... i just need to add a multiplexer to indicate the output but i dont know how!

Comment: @ZG: I've changed answer a little bit. Can you use `case` inside `mux418bit` module? `case` construct will be synthesise to multiplexer.

Comment: No,sorry im not professional in programming with verilog. this is an example that she wrote and ask us to write the code like this. moduleAU(a,b,s0,s1,out,cout,cin);
  input[7:0]a,b;
  input cin,s0,s1;
  output[7:0]out;
  output cout;
  wire[7:0]e;
  mux418bit mux(8'b00000000,b,~b,8'b00000001,s0,s1,e);
  fulladder8bit fa8(a,e,cin,cout,out);
endmodule